# How does one perform a sub query with different post types

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, rest-api

I am creating an application for a home cleaning service using the WP API.

I have two custom post types called `property` and `job`.

The `property` posts contain a list of home addresses and phone numbers.
The `job` posts contain active jobs assigned to a property.

When creating a `job` post, the editor must enter a `property_id` value so that the job can be associated with a property from the properties list via this foreign key. The `property_id` refers to the `ID` from the `property` post type.

I have a rest route defined to search for all jobs based on the phone number of the property. 
Currently I am performing two separate `wp_query` operations which is working.

- First, to fetch all properties with the phone number matching "1234".
- Then, fetch all jobs where the `property_id` matches the results from the first operation.

I understand that this is not a viable solution nor a process friendly one.
Is there a way to get the same result by using only one wp_query operation?

My lists can be represented like this:

```
# Properties
-------------------
ID    phone
1     1234
2     9999
3     5555
-------------------

# Jobs
-------------------
ID    property_id
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
-------------------
```

And, using a hard-coded phone value, my current function looks like this:

```
# get all properties with the phone number '1234'
$wp_query1 = get_posts([
    'post_type' => ['property'],
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => "phone",
        'value' => "1234",
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
]);

# place property ids into an array
foreach($wp_query1 as $post):
    $property_ids[] = $post->ID;
endforeach;

# get all jobs with property ids
$wp_query2 = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => ['job'],
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => "property_id",
        'value' => $property_ids,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
]);

# place job ids into an array
foreach($wp_query2 as $post):
    $job_ids[] = $post->ID;
endforeach;

# return job ids
return rest_ensure_response($job_ids);
```

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of the REST architecture is that endpoints are for a single type of resource, and they're queried and updated independently. What you're 'supposed' to do is query them separately in your application. So you'd query the project, and then query the related jobs when necessary. Having a single master endpoint that returns a bundle of _everything_ is not how REST is supposed to be used. The API is not your database, it's a constrained set of methods for retrieving and updating resources over the web. Your application is responsible for caching to avoid making too many requests.

Comment: @Jacob I understand what you mean. Up until now I have been using the REST routes as you say. But now I have a requirement to implement a search feature with filters. This means I need to create a custom endpoint with the ability to query between two separate post types. Is this really an antipattern or do you know of another method I could use?